# strip text with regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract text between `[` and `]` with regex in php:

Example input:

```
hello, this is [good] test about [regex] I test
```

Desired output:

```
good
regex
```

How can I extract them?

Comment: its better to extract these words using preg_match not preg_split, just use `#\[.*?\]#`

Comment: yes, I agree with you ,tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex `/\[(.*?)\]/`

```
<?php
$str='hello, this is [good] test about [regex] I test';
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => good
    [1] => regex
)
```

[image]

Comment: You should put `print_r` inside an `if` condition surrounding the result of `preg_match_all` just in case that there's no matches.

Comment: @h2ooooooo, Agreed :)

Comment: good job, thank you, my fault was preg_match instead preg_match_all, tnx